# python import best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a python module with several functions (say 10-20 functions). About 50% of those functions use an imported module (that is potentially 'heavy'). Is it 'better practice' to:

1- Call the 'import' function inside each of the 5 functions that require it.

or

2- Make that import in the module header - even though 50% of the functions in that module do NOT use the imported module.

I guess the larger question is what's the more 'pythonic' to decide whether imports are done within the module, within specific classes or within methods (functions) in those classes.

Comment: For that you can check PEP8.

Comment: the short answer is "it depends" are you calling those functions a lot?  because then it will import every time you call the function.

Comment: Why is the imported module "heavy"? That seems like the anti-pattern to me.

Comment: Why not make 2 modules, putting the 50% that require the import in the same module of course?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: trying to: 1- optimize for performance, 2- avoid circular imports (can be done in different ways), 3- apply best practices (PEP8, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

An import is only a **name binding**. It is better to import the whole module at once because it will search the module in your files only one time.

You can find more information here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html